# unable to compare strings in Robot tests due to source string

Tags: testing, automation, scripting, robotframework

What I'm  trying to do is getting a record from a table and comparing it against the text in an element in the web UI.

I exec into the docker and run the command to pull out the top record which works fine

`+++ docker exec -it 60493033cec6 /bin/sh -c 'mysql -uroot -ppassword -Bse "use requestdb; select REQUEST_ID from infra_active_requests limit 1;"'`

The echo command for the above outputs the below:-

```
++ req_id=$'0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3\r'

++ echo Record: $'0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3\r'    

Record: 0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3          notice there is no \r here

++ export $'req_id=0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3\r'

++ req_id=$'0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3\r' `// \r included in the string here.
```

AND in the tests I am using the below statement to compare the strings

```
${result}  Get Text  xpath = //*[@id="mat-tab-content-0-0"]/div/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[1]/a
Should be equal as Strings   ${result}    ${REQ_ID}  //REQ_ID has the request id created before
${REQ_ID} =  Fetch From Left ${REQ_ID} \r `     // to remove the \r
```

I am trying to set the value of the outcome from the db query on to ${RESULT} using

`${REQ_ID} =  Fetch From Left ${REQ_ID} \r`

Am i doing this right? The String library is imported

The error I get is:-

```
1. No keyword with name 'Fetch From Left ${REQ_ID} \r' found.
```

or

```
2. 0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3 != 0327902d-6346-4c61-94b2-9da532bc7ef3   ///when run without the fetch from left command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Fetch from left` keyword there should be at least 2 spaces between the keyword and the arguments. In your code there seems to be only one between `Fetch From Left`, `${REQ_ID}` and `\r`. This is why you get the `No keyword with name 'Fetch From Left ${REQ_ID} \r' found.` error.

Also, if you're not able to compare the strings due to the `\r` character, you should compare the string after removing `/r`. Exchange the positions of line numbers 2 and 3.

```
${result}  Get Text  xpath = //*[@id="mat-tab-content-0-0"]/div/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[1]/a
${REQ_ID} =  Fetch From Left  ${REQ_ID}  \r      // to remove the \r
Should be equal as Strings   ${result}    ${REQ_ID}  //REQ_ID has the request id created before
```

I'm almost sure this should work. Do comment if it doesn't.